# rename table with partitions in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

is it safe to rename a table with partitions? would the partitions need to be rebuilt?

basically i have a large database at 87G. I need to do some upgrades/schema changes. my intention was to rename the large data tables, make necessary changes/upgrades and then back fill the table afterwards.